# Orthonormal basis construction for Hermetian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning, symmetric-matrices

I was going thru wiki regarding this proof. I understood the following

Given a matrix $A$ of order $n$, its characteristic polynomial is of degree $n$ and so it will have $n$ roots(by fundamental theorem of algebra). Let the root be $\lambda_1$ and corresponding eigen vector be $\vec e_1$. Now consider $K = \text{Span} \{ \vec e_1\}^{\perp}$. Now again we have $n-1$ degree characteristic polynomial and so again (by above) we have an eigen value and corresponding eigen vector...

In this way we can construct orthonormal basis for $ A$(Hermetian or symmetric matrix of order $n$).

But in wiki "The spectral theorem holds also for symmetric maps on finite-dimensional real inner product spaces, but the **existence of an eigenvector does not follow immediately from the fundamental theorem of algebra**. To prove this, consider $A$ as a Hermitian matrix and use the fact that all eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real." --> why the existence do not immediately follow from $n-1$ degree characteristic polynomial? It should right? kindly elaborate.

Wiki link - [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20linear%20algebra,diagonal%20matrix%20in%20some%20basis.&text=In%20more%20abstract%20language%2C%20the,about%20commutative%20C*-algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20linear%20algebra,diagonal%20matrix%20in%20some%20basis.&text=In%20more%20abstract%20language%2C%20the,about%20commutative%20C*-algebras).

in proof of this theorem - Theorem. If $A$ is Hermitian, there exists an orthonormal basis of V consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. Each eigenvalue is real....]

Comment: What matrix are you considering when you refer to having an $(n-1)$-degree characteristic polynomial? A matrix whose columns are each orthogonal to $e_1$ would seemingly be rectangular and thus not have a characteristic polynomial.

Comment: sir A is symmetric or hermitian matrix. e1 has eigen value $\lambda_1$. Charactersitic polynomial is of degree n. When i exclude factor of 1st eigen value, the remaining polynomial is of degree n-1 right?

Comment: my doubt is on bold lines mentioned in wiki. Why fundamental theorem of algebra is not sufficient for existence of eigen vector?

Comment: The quotient is of degree $n-1$, certainly, but you're claiming that said polynomial is also a characteristic polynomial. If so, of what matrix is it the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: sir I am considering characteristic polynomial of A. My understanding is limited. I did not know the other direction. What matrix i get from the n-1 order characteristic polynomial. Coming from characteristic polynomial of A, after getting 1 eigen value, if i exclude that factor from characteristic polynomial of A, for sure , i know that i get n-1 degree polynomial